# accept payment on vaulted cards

Tags: paypal, payment, braintree

I have created a paypal business account and I want to vault credit cards to accept payments using paypal v.zero library. I have tested everything using a sandbox account but did not work using my paypal business account. I keep getting the following error

```
{
"creditCardVerification": null,
"transaction": null,
"subscription": null,
"errors":{
"allDeepValidationErrors":[
{"attribute": "payment_method_token", "code": "TRANSACTION_PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKEN_CARD_TYPE_IS_NOT_ACCEPTED", "message": "Payment instrument type is not accepted by this merchant account."…},
{"attribute": "merchant_account_id", "code": "TRANSACTION_PAYMENT_INSTRUMENT_NOT_SUPPORTED_BY_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT", "message": "Merchant account does not support payment instrument."…}
],
"allValidationErrors":[]
},
"parameters":{
"transaction[type]": "sale",
"transaction[payment_method_token]": "xxxxxx",
"transaction[amount]": "1"
},
"message": "Payment instrument type is not accepted by this merchant account.\nMerchant account does not support payment instrument.",
"target": null,
"success": false
}
```

Comment: Did you receive this error when you used your Braintree Sandbox or Production account? If Production, did you follow the [PayPal setup guide](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/setup-guide)?

Comment: No, I have tested the sandbox and it works just fine. after talking to the braintree support, they said that I cannot use their vault for credit cards. I can only use it for saving paypal account which is unfortunate by the way. I wonder if there is an other way to vault credit card and accept payment using paypal.

Answer (score 1):

error in  `"transaction[amount]": "1"` you have pass currency with amount 
use `"transaction[amount]": {"value":"1.0", "currency":"USD"}`